# Error assigning a boolean value in a custom class extends from TextField (FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I started learning JavaFX and ran into this problem: I have a TextBox class extendsfrom TextField

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TextBox extends TextField {

    private int maxLength = 255;
    private boolean onlyDigits;

    public TextBox(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
        String oldText = getText();
        super.replaceText(start, end, text);

        if (!verify()){
            setText(oldText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String text) {
        String oldText = getText();
        super.replaceSelection(text);

        if (!verify()){
            setText(oldText);
        }
    }

    private boolean verify() {
        String text = getText();

        if (text =="")
            return true;

        if (text.length() > maxLength) {
            return false;
        }
        if (onlyDigits && !Converter.StringToInt(text).isSuccess()){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int getMaxLength() {
        return maxLength;
    }

    public void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
        if (maxLength >= 0)
            this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public void setOnlyDigits(boolean onlyDigits) {
        this.onlyDigits = onlyDigits;
    }

    public boolean isOnlyDigits() {
        return onlyDigits;
    }
}
```

When using the following FXML, I get an error:

```
<TextBox
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                maxLength="2"
                onlyDigits="true"
                fx:id="tbNumberVertex" />
```

> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onlyDigits='true', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.

But in case of maxLength everything works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what is happening here is that, because the property `onlyDigits` begins with the text `"on"`, the FXML parser is assuming it's an event handler property. (Like, for example, `onAction`.) So it's assuming the value assigned, `true`, refers to a function defined in a script in the FXML.

(For what it's worth, I'd consider this to be a bug.)

Change the name of the property, e.g. to `useOnlyDigits` by changing the names of the methods:

```
public void setUseOnlyDigits(boolean onlyDigits) {
    this.onlyDigits = onlyDigits;
}

public boolean isUseOnlyDigits() {
    return onlyDigits;
}
```

and update the FXML accordingly:

```
<TextBox
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
    maxLength="2"
    useOnlyDigits="true"
    fx:id="tbNumberVertex" />
```